# Class fixtures in Python's unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm trying to understand [class fixtures](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#class-and-module-fixtures) in Python's `unittest` module. In order to speed up testing, I'd like to create an 'expensive' connection object just once in each class. At first blush I thought of doing it like this:

```
import unittest
import rethinkdb as r

class TestRethink(unittest.TestCase):
    conn = r.connect('localhost', 28016)

    def test_table_list(self):
        r.table_list().run(self.conn)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

It seems from the documentation, however, that one is supposed to do it like this:

```
import unittest
import rethinkdb as r

class TestRethink(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.conn = r.connect('localhost', 28016)

    def test_table_list(self):
        r.table_list().run(self.conn)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

What is the difference between the two approaches? In both cases the RethinkDB connection object is a class variable, isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the difference between the two approaches? In both cases the RethinkDB connection object is a class variable, isn't it?

the main differences are scope and order of execution, a class variable will get defined and executed when the class itself will be loaded, whereas the `setupClass()` method will be called by `unittest` at the time of running your tests, when that class will be instanciated (it's acting a bit like a constructor).

In your minimal example this should be of little difference, but if you subclass your `TestRethink` class, then it will. Because in the first case you'll share a single DB connection for all your subclasses, whereas with the setup/teardown you'll have one connection per subclass.

Answer (score 3):

### difference #1

on the first approach. `conn` is a class member of `TestRethink` class.

on the second approach (`unittest` approach), every subclass of `TestRethink` will have its **own different connection** meaning every `TestCase` class will have its own connection instance.

example of the difference when using `@classmethod`:

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def setup(cls):
        cls.conn = 'my connection for %r' % cls

class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    pass


# setup the tests
B.setup()
C.setup()

b = B()
c = C()
print(b.conn)
print(c.conn)
```

this code outputs:

```
my connection for <class '__main__.B'>
my connection for <class '__main__.C'>
```

### difference #2

`unittest` will handle exceptions during setup of subclasses and will print more verbose info about the failure which will be easier to debug why the test failed.

I suggest using `unittest` approach or try the [`pytest`](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) module which has nice API to deal with fixtures.